# Does mongo-scala-driver support GridFs?

Tags: mongodb, scala, gridfs, mongo-scala-driver

I look at their documentation here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.1/ and I could not find where it is mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `mongo-scala-driver` is written from scratch (it's not a java driver wrapper) and it **does not support GridFS**.

You can take a look at ReactiveMongo - [it offers an API for GridFS](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.gridfs.GridFS).

Otherwise, you can always use the [Java driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's coming.
Just found this directory on github

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/tree/master/driver/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/gridfs

and this example

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/tour/GridFSTour.scala